# install llvm ->llvmlite->llvmpy->numba on centos, error on install llvmlite

Tags: python, llvm, llvmlite

I notice that LLVM 3.3 is deprecated and start to install llvm 3.8.1->llvmlite->llvmpy->numba

I download and compile llvm 3.8.1 source (I am not sure whether I should download other packages like clang)

and simply cmake.  (I didn't find REQUIRES_RTTI=1 options this time)

then I point LLVM_CONFIG to the llvm-config produced by cmake and try to pip install --user livelite, however:

/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [libllvmlite.so] Error 1
    3.8.1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pip-build-Kr1kPD/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 152, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/pip-build-Kr1kPD/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 142, in main
    main_posix('linux', '.so')
  File "/tmp/pip-build-Kr1kPD/llvmlite/ffi/build.py", line 134, in main_posix
    subprocess.check_call(['make', '-f', makefile])
  File "/usr/local/software/python2/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make', '-f', 'Makefile.linux']' returned non-zero exit status 2
error: command '/usr/local/bin/python2' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
    Command "/usr/local/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools,      tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Kr1kPD/llvmlite/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0a3VQ7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Kr1kPD/llvmlite/
```

It maybe due to I didnot install libedit-dev.

Do you whether it is caused by this? and Can I install libedit-dev on centos without root authority?

---

### Below is obsolete information, which should be ignored, keep it only as historical record.

I install llvm according to this instruction, and encounter the error below when import it.
http://www.llvmpy.org/

Can anyone tell me what is the problem.

I download the LLVM source code, the version is 3.3

BTW: I set llvm with:
"./configure --enable-optimized --prefix=/home/wliax/llvm_liwei"

However, after  "REQUIRES_RTTI=1 make", the compiled library is at:

"/home/wliax/llvm/llvm-3.3.src/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-config"

so I then use:

"LLVM_CONFIG_PATH=/home/wliax/llvm/llvm-3.3.src/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-config python setup.py install --user"

so the llvmpy lib is at "/homes/wliax/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"

> > > import llvm
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/homes/wliax/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/llvm/**init**.py", line 7, in 
> > >           from llvmpy import extra
> > >         File "/homes/wliax/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/llvmpy/extra.py", line 6, in 
> > >           from llvmpy import _api
> > >       ImportError: /homes/wliax/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/llvmpy/_api.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE

Comment: are you on windows? if yes try `pip install llvm` or download the file and pip install from the directory

Comment: Hi: I am in centOS.

Comment: On the llvm page they say it is a problem of not enabling REQUIRES_RTTI, but I already give the command "REQUIRES_RTTI=1 make". So I am not sure whether it is the problem.

Comment: http://llvm.org/docs/Packaging.html have you read this?

Comment: I notice that llvm 3.3 is deprecated, so I change to llvm 3.8.1 and then try install llvm-lite. but then another problem happend

Comment: Why don't you try install with `pip` or `anaconda`? Even on `CentOS` you could install these tools.